# Java: Count Inversions Algorithm logic went wrong

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write the Count inversion algorithm. It works on an array of size 10. However, things went terribly wrong, when I tried to test on an array of size 100000. I was still able to sort the array but the number of inversions is NEGATIVE, which is wrong. I don't understand which part of my logic went wrong.

My main logic: I created an array object called `myArray` and it has a `CountSplitInv` instance method that is suppose to sort the sub-arrays and return number of inversions involved.

Please help me out. I have been stuck in this for a long time now and I still wasn't able to figure out what went wrong.

I have a feeling that I don't understand Recursion concept fully.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class myArray{
    private int[] input_array;
    private int nElems;

    public myArray(int max){
        input_array = new int[max];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(int value){
        input_array[nElems++] = value;
    }

    public void display(){
        for(int j = 0; j < nElems; j++){
            System.out.print(input_array[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

     public void SortAndCount(){
        int[] output_array = new int[nElems];
        int ans = SortNInversionCounts(output_array,0, nElems -1);
        System.out.println("number of inversions IS: " + ans);
     }

    public int SortNInversionCounts(int[] output_array, int lowerBound, int upperBound){
        if(lowerBound == upperBound){
            return 0;
        } else{
            int mid = (lowerBound + upperBound)/2;
            int x, y , z;
            x = SortNInversionCounts(output_array, lowerBound, mid);
            y = SortNInversionCounts(output_array, mid+1, upperBound);
            z = CountSplitInv(output_array, lowerBound, mid+1, upperBound);
            return x + y + z;
        }
    }

    public int CountSplitInv(int[] output_array, int lowPtr, int highPtr, int upperBound){
        int j = 0;
        int lowerBound = lowPtr;
        int mid = highPtr - 1;
        int n = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;

        int numOfInversions = 0;


        while(lowPtr <= mid && highPtr <= upperBound){
            if( input_array[lowPtr] < input_array[highPtr]){
                output_array[j++] = input_array[lowPtr++];
            } else{
                output_array[j++] = input_array[highPtr++];
                // WHERE I count number of inversions 
                numOfInversions = numOfInversions + (mid - lowPtr + 1);
            }
        }

        while(lowPtr <= mid){
            output_array[j++] = input_array[lowPtr++];
        }

        while(highPtr <= upperBound){
            output_array[j++] = input_array[highPtr++];
        }

        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            input_array[lowerBound+j] = output_array[j];
        }

        return numOfInversions;
    }
}

class NumOfInversionsApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        // Read input file
        FileInputStream fil = new FileInputStream("IntegerArray.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fil));

        myArray in_array = new myArray(100000);
        String element = null;
        while( ( element = br.readLine()) != null){
            in_array.insert( Integer.parseInt(element) );
        }



        // input_array.display();
        in_array.SortAndCount();

        // input_array.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything that looks obviously wrong. However, an array of 100000 may too many inversions to fit in an it. Maybe try using long instead?

Comment: omg, you were right, everything works, once I did `long numOfInversions` instead of `int numOfInversions`. But why is this happening ? I don't understand.

Comment: The maximum value a 32-bit integer can hold is 2^31-1. If you go beyond that, then something that is knows as an overflow will happen. For example, let's say instead of 32-bits we only have 4 bits. So the maximum value is 2^3-1 = 7 = 0111 (binary), if we add 1, then we get 1000. Remember that the last bit is the sign bit, and so we get a negative number.

Comment: This tutorial, even though it is for begginers, has the data types very well explained. The int should be of particular interest.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm

The knowledge that leads to understanding signed and unsigned int may be of help too.

Comment: How come Java doesn't complain this overflow error then ? Is there a way to make this error show up ?

Comment: I think there is no overflow-check at runtime, which means it cannot complain. Java isn't fully object-oriented and `int` (as well as `long` are primitive datatypes - a mere sequence of bytes that just happens to represent a number. In most cases however, overflows won't happen, but even changing to `long` will not give you an infinite pool of numbers. If I'm not mistaken, you `BigInteger` can be of arbitrary precision and will not suffer from overflows - at a performance cost (creating objects, dispatching methods, ...).